# Is it possible to change the windows inc ruler unit

Tags: windows, windows-10, developer-tools

I'm looking for a nice pixel ruler for windows. I knew, that the windows ink screenshot tool has a built in ruler. But I don't know which unit is used in that tool and anyhow, there are obsiously no pixels used. Is is possible to change the unit to pixels? Are there some good rulers out there for windows? It's so easy with a Mac, since you can simply measure with the screenshot tool on the fly.

Comment: Maybe try [Snip](https://mix.office.com/snip) from Microsoft. It will display the size in pixels as you drag the selection box.

Comment: That's just perfect! I tried snipping tool, but not snip... I think that's a valuable answer to this question for future visitors. Feel free to create the answer and I will check it :)

Comment: Do you know about any shortcuts for this tool?

Comment: Nevermind, I found out, that you can change the shortcuts when you click on 'library' -> 'Settings'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While I don't know how to change the units on the Windows Ink Ruler, Microsoft has a free program, [Snip](https://mix.office.com/snip), which shows the size of your selection in pixels as you take a screenshot. I've been using it as a replacement for the built-in Snipping Tool and it works great.